# Does X3D support keyframe Animations, how to convert animated GLB file into X3D including Animations?

Tags: animation

Does X3D support keyframe Animations? I have a blender file (originally GLB file) with Animations and different Actions and want them convert into X3D file. How can I do this including the animations? Model is converting without animations.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question about using Blender rather than about the file format itself. Blender does seem to have a built-in importer/exporter addon for X3D (Import-Export:  Web3D X3d/VMRL2 format), but the Blender [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/addons/import_export/scene_x3d.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#web3d-x3d-vrml2) entry doesn't even mention animation.